# Proyecto funciona en localhost pero en host de produccion no encuentra las rutas

Tags: php, codeigniter-3

Tengo un proyecto que funciona al 100 en localhost pero al subirlo a produccion no encuentra las rutas.
El proyecto lo tengo dentro de una carpeta en la raiz   raiz/desarrollo/proyecto
ruta de app/config

```
https://www.bridgecom.mx/desarrollo/fin_new_12_20_22/

jquery.min.js:4          POST http://bridge_cms.test/cms/welcome/loggear 404 (Not Found)
```

**Not Found
The requested URL /index.php was not found on this serve**

Mis contraladores tienen la primera letra mayuscula y las demas en minusculas.

este es mi htaccess

```
RewriteEngine on
RewriteCond $1 !^(index\.php|images|robots\.txt|assets)
#RewriteRule ^(.*) index.php/$1 [L]
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ /index.php?$1 [L]
```

Comment: hay un archivo config donde se configuran las rutas base, verificalo, `app/config/App.php` en la variable  `public $baseURL`

Comment: asi es pero como te comente si me funciona el local , pero no entiendo a lo que refieres

Comment: en local siempre funciona por que el producion la url cambia pues usas un dominio y no la palabra localhost

Comment: ya tengo configurada mi url https://www.dominio.com.mx/desarrollo/carpeta_deproyecto_12_20_22/